# iOS: FBSDKShareDialog Opening App but Not Allowing User to Share Link

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to integrate the new Facebook SDK into an app I'm working on and for some reason whenever I try and share a link the share screen doesn't come up. I get kicked to the Facebook app (or the web app if there's no Facebook app installed), but I never get an option to share the link I'm trying to get the user to post.

I've pretty much followed the example on the Facebook developer site to a T, but for reference, here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)shareToFacebook:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Share to Facebook");
    FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [FBSDKShareLinkContent new];
    content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    content.contentTitle = @"Test Post!";
    content.contentDescription = @"Content Description;
    FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [FBSDKShareDialog new];
    [shareDialog setMode:FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic];
    [shareDialog setShareContent:content];
    [shareDialog setFromViewController:self];
    [shareDialog show];
//    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];
}
```

As you can see above, I've tried using both the convenience method Facebook uses in their documentation, as well as being more verbose, but both produce the same result (opening the Facebook app but not giving the user an option to share any content). Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually turned out to be a small typo in my info.plist for the app. Just a heads up to anyone else getting a similar error to check over all the information they have setup there and be sure it's all correct.

Comment: can you tell me what you did in plist

Comment: @abdulrauf618 If I recall, I had just forgotten to put "fb" in front of my URL scheme when adding it to the plist.

Comment: after sharing are you getting proper return, now my message going to friends but when ever it comes back, it always coming in sharerDidCancel :(

Answer (score 2):

add to you code

1. `[shareDialog setDelegate:self]`
2. `<FBSDKSharingDelegate>` to your class
3. `FBSDKSharing` code

   ```
   #pragma mark - FBSDKSharingDelegate
   - (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults :(NSDictionary *)results {
      NSLog(@"FB: SHARE RESULTS=%@\n",[results debugDescription]);
   }

    - (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
      NSLog(@"FB: ERROR=%@\n",[error debugDescription]);
   }

   - (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer {
      NSLog(@"FB: CANCELED SHARER=%@\n",[sharer debugDescription]);
   }
   ```

set break point in the `didFailWithError` and You can see many interesting underlying errors descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

This this example for share image from application to facebook with using swift

```
     func shareWithFacebook(){

            let share : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()

            share.imageURL = NSURL(string: "image url")
            share.contentTitle = "content description "
            share.contentURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com")

            let dialog : FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
            dialog.fromViewController = self
            dialog.shareContent = share
            let facebookURL = NSURL(string: "fbauth2://app")
            if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(facebookURL!)){
                dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.Native
            }else{
                dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.FeedWeb
            }
            dialog.show()
}
```

Don't forgot to add facebook framework

Answer (score 0):

As it states in the `FBSDKShareDialogMode.h`:

> @discussion The automatic mode will progressively check the availability of different modes and open the most
>    appropriate mode for the dialog that is available.

So just choose another [Share Dialog Mode](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareDialogMode.h).

Comment: This isn't really solving the issue though...I've tried other modes (FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet, FBSDKShareDialogModeNative, etc.) but it still doesn't pull in the content I'm trying to set. At best I can get the link, but not the `contentTitle` or `contentDescription` to display by changing the Share Dialog Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on only one iPhone whereas in other iPhones it worked fine. It turned out that the Facebook app in that device was outdated and hence the FBSDKShareDialog wasn't showing up. Once the Facebook app was updated to the latest version, the FBSDKShareDialog started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this mode:

```
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedWeb
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11115135)

Comment: @VojtechVrbka How does this not provide an answer? It might be completely wrong, [but that doesn't mean we should delete it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1849664) Please pay attention when reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

To share on Facebook through Native iOS app.
We need updated FB SDK installed in app.

I used Pods to installed.
link to get pod set up into Mac: https://cocoapods.org

Write pod file name in podfile :

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

or
manual installation please follow : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

after successful installation of FB SDKs.

Write code on button action:

```
        FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
        content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://AppLink"];
        content.quote = @"Sample description of app";

        [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                     withContent:content
                                        delegate:nil];
```

It will automatically handle Native or Web (if not installed.)